# VSCode Python IntelliSense Not working On Remove Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I use VSCode "Remote-SSH" to access a VM to do all my coding.

On the VM I have installed the "Python" and "Pylance" extensions hoping to get IntelliSense autocomplete.

My python interpreter is not in the "typical" `/usr/bin/python3` location. So I have the following setting in my VM's setting.json:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/some/path/to/3.6.8/python3",
```

I have successfully enabled python lint. Although my IntelliSense autocomplete isn't working at all. When I type I don't see any pulldown menu or error messages.

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Did you try another Python version and see if it works? Python 3.6 is clearly end of life.

Comment: Yes I have, I’ve tried multiple different python versions with no luck.